# How BatchNormalization in keras works?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, normalization

I want to know how BatchNormalization works in keras, so I write the code:

```
X_input = keras.Input((2,))
X = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)(X_input)
model1 = keras.Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X)
```

the input is a batch of two dimenstions vector, and normalizing it along axis=1, then print the output:

```
a = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
print('a=')
print(a)
print('output=')
print(model1.predict(a,batch_size=2))
```

and the output is:

```
a=
array([[0, 1],
   [2, 3]])
output=
array([[ 0.        ,  0.99950039],
   [ 1.99900079,  2.9985013 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I can not figure out the results. As far as I know, the mean of the batch should be ([0,1] + [2,3])/2 = [1,2], the var is 1/2*(([0,1] - [1,2])^2 + ([2,3]-[1,2])^2) = [1,1]. Finally, normalizing it with (x - mean)/sqrt(var), therefore the results are [-1, -1] and [1,1], where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[BatchNormalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization) will substract the mean, divide by the variance, apply a factor gamma and an offset beta. **If** these parameters would actually be the mean and variance of your batch, the result would be centered around zero with variance 1.

But they are not. The keras [BatchNormalization layer](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py) stores these as weights that can be trained, called *moving_mean*, *moving_variance*, *beta* and *gamma*. They are initialized as *beta=0*, *gamma=1*, *moving_mean=0* and *moving_variance=1*. Since you don't have any train steps, BatchNorm does not change your values.

So, why don't you get exactly your input values? Because there is another parameter *epsilon* (a small number), which gets added to the variance. Therefore, all values are divided by *1+epsilon* and end up a little bit below their input values.

Comment: I still don't understand why the input values do not change. In normalization, I get [-1, -1] and [1,1], even if it mutiply gamma and add beta, I can not get the same number. Also, I tried batch_size = 4 with 4 random input vectors and I still get the same number.

Comment: BatchNormalization does not calculate mean and variance like you do, but these are (constant) parameters. Since you do not train this layer, they still have their initial value of mean=0 and variance=1.